# Web Service on Domain Joined VM on Azure

Tags: azure

I have scenario where my VM is domain joined along with my own DNS Server and I deployed the bunch of Web Service but unable to access outside even after opening the relevant endpoints.

on the Azure VM I can able to access the deployed web service like machinename.domainname.com but the cloud service name is different azwebservice.cloudapp.net which is not same.

I have open the needed endpoints as well and added the same port in firewall as a inbound ports but no luck.

How can I resolve this and access the deployed service from outside of VM Please advise.

/Harshal

Comment: When you say outside the VM do you mean on the internet or on your internal network?

Comment: Are you on IIS on Windows Server ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are on IIS on Windows Server

You may want to test a number of things:

- Is your IIS Site binding set with a Host Name?
- Your endpoint is open at the Azure load balancing level. Does your Windows Firewall also let traffic flow into the server thru that port?

  - can you test from another VM in the same domain? Does that work? Are your Windows Firewall settings the same for domain and public traffic?
- is CORS enabled? If your web service is called from another domain, then the web service must allow cross origin resource sharing